# How can I find increased column in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in SQL.

dbo.DataSensor and dbo.Dealers

```
     dbo.Dealers

  OID   Name     Location  DeviceID 
   1    BLABLA    BLABLA     1234
   2    ABC       BLABLA     232
   3    XYZ       BLABLA     412
   4    CDS       BLABLA     3421
   (...)
```

When Dealers takes fuel from oil Tanker by read DriverCard, valve of Dealer is opening and Device send to SQL Valve=1 and CardID=blabla.LevelTank1  increase after filling from Tanker.

```
 dbo.DataSensor

 OID  DeviceID    readTime             LevelTank1   Valve       CardID
 1     1234      2014-01-22 16:26:01     45         1           a12xyz 
 2     232       2014-01-22 14:26:01     70         1           sd211
 3     412       2014-01-22 13:26:01     80         1           sf212
 4     3421      2014-01-22 12:26:01     35         1           fs2134
 (...)
```

But sometimes LevelTank1 of some Dealers increases when Valve=0 and CardID='' .How can I find  all  DeviceID in this instance at last 30 days ?

Comment: You should post what you have so far (sql code).

Comment: Card is empty?ow can I find all DeviceID in this instance in 30 days ?on what condition

Comment: when Valve=0 and Card=' '

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: change your whens to wheres. WHERE Valve = 0 and (Card is null or Card = '')...lol. LIMIT DATE_SUB(readtime, interval 30 days) is what im concluding, p.s NOT REAL SQL, just psuedocode trying to figure this out.

Comment: sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @GordonLinoff SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: SO When a Dealer opens valve to get's fuel, he has an entry for readtime, and valve = 1, when it closes is that recorded as valve = 0 is there another entry added to bottom table?? CardID is set based on the dealer..is there code for how LevelTank1 is updated? Is it a trigger? there could be underlying problem if LevelTank is being updated when Valve is just being updated, and not increased...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple query.  I put in functions to handle white space or NULLS.  However, this makes the column not SARGABLE.  If table is large, I suggest making sure clean data goes in.  Then replace with S.CARD = ''.

```
-- Handle Nulls and empty space, return distinct list in order.
SELECT 
    DeviceId
FROM 
    dbo.DataSensor as S
WHERE 
    S.VALUE = 0 AND 
    REPLACE(COALESCE(S.CARD, ''), ' ', '') = '' AND
    S.READTIME >= DATEADD(D, -30, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
GROUP BY 
    DeviceId
ORDER BY 
    DeviceId ASC
```

Comment: One minute people are alive, and the next they just..disappear.

Comment: @CRAFTY DBA Is possible group by DeviceID ?

Comment: Or DISTINCT and possible ORDER BY.  But what the the requirements?  A Rank ordered list of unique DeviceIds?

Comment: I want to group by Dealer.Name in this query http://pastebin.com/VAtDWinj When I try group by Dealer.Name  I get this error : Column 'S.DeviceId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.